# Chrome giving me "Download Failed" on iOS devices using Javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-chrome, redirect

I would like to display a thank you page to the end user after an .ipa or and .apk file is downloaded.

I've been testing the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DownloadAndRedirect()
{
   var DownloadURL = "http://domain/file.ipa";
   var RedirectURL = "/thankyou.html";
   var RedirectPauseSeconds = 9;
   location.href = DownloadURL;
   setTimeout("DoTheRedirect('"+RedirectURL+"')",parseInt(RedirectPauseSeconds*1000));
}
function DoTheRedirect(url) { window.location=url; }
</script>

<a href="javascript:DownloadAndRedirect()">Click to download</a>
```

It does work on most devices.

Tested on Android devices, both Firefox and Chrome works.

Tested on iOS devices, Safari, Opera works, but:

Chrome is giving me a warning page of "Download Failed." immediately after click the download link, with orange folder icon and an exclamation mark at the middle, and a "RETRY DOWNLOAD" link at the lower right corner.

When this page appeared, it does give me the option if I want to "Cancel" or "Install" the .ipa file.

If I don't use the Javascript method, and place the .ipa file directly in the anchor field, every browser works.

Only Mobile Chrome browser is doing this with Javascript integration.  Any solution?

Is there an alternative javascript solution that will serve my purpose across different devices and browsers?

Comment: Hello, did u fix this ?